# Commutator group of symmetries of the real plane is the group containing rotations.

Tags: group-theory

Let $A$ be the group of symmetries of $\mathbb{R}^2$ fixing the origin and $B$ the subgroup of all rotations.

I want to show that the commutator subgroup, $[A, A] = B$.

I was able to conclude that $[A, A] \subset B$ but I have trouble proving $B \subset [A, A]$.

Any ideas on how to begin?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense. There is no such thing as the "subgroup of all rotations", because the rotations are not closed under composition. For example, the composition of any two $180^\circ$ rotations about different points is not a rotation, it is instead a translation. In fact the rotations generate the entire orientation preserving subgroup.

Comment: @LeeMosher Sorry about that, I wrote it down from memory. Edited it to make it exactly from the book

Comment: What exactly is $\mathbb R^2$ in your question? Clearly you don't mean it to be merely the Cartesian product of the *set* of real numbers with itself, so there is some more structure to it. What exactly is this additional structure that you are considering? As a vector space, metric space, inner product space, …? That decides what its symmetries are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $r$ be a rotation of $\mathbb R^2$ about the origin, and let $s$ be the reflection of $\mathbb R^2$ about the $x$-axis. What is $srs^{-1}$? So what is $[s, r]$?

**Solution:**

> Observe that $srs^{-1} = r^{-1}$, and therefore, $[s, r] = srs^{-1}r^{-1} = r^{-2}$. Thus, every rotation that can be written in the form $r^{-2}$ for some rotation $r$, is a commutator. But *all* rotations of the plane (about the origin) can be written in this form — to write a rotation $\rho$ as $r^{-2}$, simply take $r$ to be the rotation in the opposite direction of $\rho$, by half the angle of $\rho$. Therefore, all rotations of $\mathbb R^2$ about the origin are commutators.